# to connect to a site with request python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to connect to a site (expressvpn). I copy cookies, headers and parameters and yet I still get a `404` error. Here is my code:

```py
def check(self, email, password):
    api_request = requests.Session()
    data = api_request.get("https://www.expressvpn.com/sign-in").text
    parser = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
    token = parser.find("input", attrs={"name":"authenticity_token"})["value"]
    cookies = {
        "landing_page" : "https://www.expressvpn.com/",
        "locale" : "",
        "_ga" : "GA1.2.1734155776.1558287705",
        "_gid" : "GA1.2.1563146683.1561287236",
        "_gcl_au" : "1.1.2068251248.1558287706",
        "_xv_web_frontend_session" : "SW5ZWkxVc0JCekNGZFRld3FGNHUrUy9uUTRZTk1URWsxZEZvaHVYSEZrRXFZK3hxQ0hNTERSM2E4NWt0N2tVTVJGSGNwbjZpZnRFNjRmdmsxc1RqenFyZ3dXV2lqc2doQ3ZUK0oxVXJuVGxrdHM5ckEyckNqUXRGNzM1a1lIMW1SelZYUEFGY3QySXdrUklWdS81bEVrbHZmMXpBSXRuSTAyT2dpdy8wbERrQVRDNHg5ODZpV3VlSXVnM1VqMXkzLS14WDc3QUp3S2ViU0JvTjJ0MWYydTh3PT0=--3242a65b9b9f9f19ded04fa2951076d86e9ae1ce",
        "km_ai" : "UeIjpnxl3F1M4jhFnmWjA23eJuM",
        "km_lv" : "x",
        "kvcd" : "1561299315371",
        "SnapABugHistory" : "2#a6794e16-371f-4400-8806-645fb34bba7f:1558293472503!579bc686-7c02-422f-bb10-572b9d9642d8:1560465017116!",
        "SnapABugUserEmail" : "SnapABugUserEmail",
        "xv_ab" : '{"fro2146_home_page_aatest":"varianta"}',
        "xv3v2ksky" : "jl2wkuyyLhX35PFeAAAAAKhW9QEAAAAAi5PbKsXFsDb1Vviqi0vHRdUpHCTvDFylj1pzqqoTBn6VK_slWWXQuJikUa8t8eNa6YXa_hWpE5dhyL5rKRBmKrKax1e1CYlXphEavYOENupju-n4mkbCKBCDh1G2DR-1d4e2ABsuqserj612c_-zicCo9n7qLjmftEnSf71bkxH8vhc3QumMSzknPvBybRQalUKLogYNVkGMXBQlCNiPV8i82P-GBvHLRHMrp4SAGvCZRijWzb2Kl8yZVeMrZ5oGkYqzWjm-OpP0VWfcqzsfLftwR0MhNPV9UFgo1ZHrckJkwk4FWLAtxOhLUQmawDB35H_5duAsjw6wtfuMUnOrPA==",
        "xvid" : "aWJRhD9qp4vfvN8s5xcBRwlcvsTy6c_fb3MITh7Y_S4=",
        "xvsrcdirect" : "1",
        "xvu95kprm" : "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--b0d052039d8c55ce159a8f961f880e9e99f88537"

    }
    headers = {
        "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0".encode("utf-8"),
        "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8".encode("utf-8"),
        "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language" : "en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
        "Content-Length" : "207",
        "DNT" : "1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Referer" : "https://www.expressvpn.com/sign-in",
        "Connection" : "keep-alive",
        "Host" : "www.expressvpn.com"
    }
    payload = {
        "utf8" : "✓",
        "username" : email,
        "password" : password,
        "authenticity_token" : token
    }

    reponse = api_request.post('https://www.expressvpn.com/sign-in', data=payload, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    print(reponse.status_code)
    login_account = api_request.get('https://www.expressvpn.com/subscriptions')
```

and I had another question that every cookie and header parameter is mandatory?

edit :

with `print(response.text)` i have :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.

<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: P3GRCYoUnFhU1M3o8p1FqSUwi35zk1fMu0iIwrY8FLA4swlRiKDrBg==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Is this a problem with cloudflare?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code:

- You are sending the `POST` request to the wrong link
- Your payloads dictionary doesn't look correct

**I would recommend doing the following changes:**

1. Instead of sending a `POST` request to:

   ```
   https://www.expressvpn.com/sign-in
   ```

   try sending it to

   ```
   https://www.expressvpn.com/sessions
   ```
2. try replacing:

   ```
     payload = {
           "utf8" : "✓",
           "username" : email,
           "password" : password,
           "authenticity_token" : token
       }
   ```

   with:

   ```
     payload = {
           "utf8" : "\xe2\x9c\x93",
           "username" : email,
           "password" : password,
           "authenticity_token" : token
       }
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: before I had a 404 error and with this change I have a 403 error

Comment: revert back to `data=` and try this (I just edited my answer)

Comment: same error 403, I edit my message to add new information

Comment: I edited my answer should work now. Thanks for including the extra info, it definitely helps

Comment: if it doesn't work try removing `cookies=cookies` from the `POST` request

Comment: i try with https://www.expressvpn.com/sessions and i have eror 403 same if i removing cookies from the POST

Comment: try removing `"Host"` from your headers. It's very strange I don't seem to be getting the same result as you

Comment: Hmmm, I’m working right now I’ll try solving this problem tonight

Comment: Nobody to an idea?